# Pagination table - Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I have a `table` with 200 rows, and I would like to show them in different pages (10 per page)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered pointer">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let car of cars;let i = index">
          <td>{{car.ID}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very good explanation on how to implement pagination in Angular:

[Angular 2/5 - Pagination Example with Logic like Google](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google)

You can see an example of how I implemented this on a sample website I made, and you can get the full source code at my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/Stanza987/angular-pagination).